# How force UnityContainer to create instances of objects in the same thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, unity-container

I think that `UnityContainer` creates instances of classes in a different threads. 
I have an WPF application and authorization information I keep in `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal`.

Is there any way to force `UnityContainer` to work in single thread?

Comment: You think that it creates Threads or did you observe/investigate?

Comment: I some rare cases UserApi created by UnityContainer looks into System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal and it appears to be empty.

Comment: It seems very unlikely that Unity will spawn multiple tasks or threads during a single call to `container.Resolve<T>`. So you will have to show more code demonstrating your problem. We won't be able to answer your question in its current state.